# Request for clarification of bottom bracket threading

Tags: bottom-bracket, threaded-bottom-bracket

I know that bottom brackets have a left-hand thread on the right side, and a right-hand thread on the left side.
But I fail to understand why.
I would have thought it should be the other way round, to ensure that the pedaling movement ensures the halves remain screwed in tight?
Can somebody explain where I am wrong?

Comment: FWIW Italian-threaded bottom brackets are right-threaded on both sides and work equally well. It is not that important.

Comment: Relevant question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/17701/6852

Comment: Just a link to this topic: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/brandt/left.html